# ValueError: readexactly size can not be less than zero telethon how to fix?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

```
Unexpected exception in the receive loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fazuq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 324, in _recv_loop
    data = await self._recv()
  File "C:\Users\fazuq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 367, in _recv
    return await self._codec.read_packet(self._reader)
  File "C:\Users\fazuq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\tcpfull.py", line 27, in read_packet
    body = await reader.readexactly(packet_len - 8)
  File "C:\Users\fazuq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 709, in readexactly
    raise ValueError('readexactly size can not be less than zero')
ValueError: readexactly size can not be less than zero
```

I get this error, perhaps it is associated with frequent requests, but although I have an exception call, the error still remains, what is the reason for this? I tried to invoke exceptions in different ways, at different points in the code, but it's useless. The error remains, broke through several forums, reread the library, but did not find the necessary information

```
async def get_voice_messages(client: TelegramClient, dialog_id: int):
    try:
        messages: list = await client.get_messages(dialog_id, None, filter = InputMessagesFilterVoice)
    except ValueError:
        print('я тута')
        return
    except:
        print('или тута')
        return
    print('See dialog: {}'.format(dialog_id))
    for message in messages:
        try:
            if message.out:
                # await client.delete_messages(message.peer_id.user_id, message_ids=[message.id])
                print('Success delete message: {} from peer: {}'.format(message.id, message.peer_id.user_id))
        except:
            print('No have voice messages!')


async def get_dialog_list() -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async with TelegramClient(config['session_name'], config['api_id'], config['api_hash'], loop = loop) as client:
        try:
            dialogs: list = await client.get_dialogs(ignore_migrated = True)
        except ValueError:
            return

        tasks: list = []
        for dialog in dialogs:
            try:
                if not dialog.is_channel and not dialog.is_group and not dialog.entity.bot:
                    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_voice_messages(client, dialog.id)))
            except ValueError:
                continue
        start_tasks: tuple = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print('Success delete all messages!')

def start_thread() -> None:
    asyncio.run(get_dialog_list())
```

Comment: at what point in the code?

Comment: I don't know, sorry :( that's just what the error message says.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the Telethon library. [Please report the issue in GitHub](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues), along with clear reproduction steps, so that maintainers are able to reproduce the problem and have a chance at fixing it.

Comment: You can't catch the exception because it occurs in another task.  You can figure that out from the traceback, since none of the code in your try block appears in the stack trace above the point where the exception happens.